# Is un-initialized integer always default to 0 in c?

Tags: c, default-value, initialization

I'm reading source code of nginx and find it's not initializing many of the numerical variables, including `ngx_int_t ngx_last_process;`,here `ngx_int_t` defined as `long int`

```
#if 0
    ngx_last_process = 0;
#endif
```

So here @Igor Sysoev think it unnecessary to do the initialization?

But in the programe it's assuming the default value is `0`:

```
    for (s = 0; s < ngx_last_process; s++) {
        if (ngx_processes[s].pid == -1) {
            break;
        }
    }
```

Is it guranteed that un-initialized variable will have `0` value in c at all?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

*External* and *static* variables are initialized to zero by default, this is guaranteed. *Automatic* and *register* variables that do not have en explicit initializer will have an indeterminate value (either an unspecified value or a trap representation).

From The Standard:

**C89**

6.5.7:

> If an object that has static storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, it is initialized implicitly as if every member that has
>   arithmetic type were assigned 0 and every member that has pointer type
>   were assigned a null pointer constant.  If an object that has
>   automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is
>   indeterminate.

**C99**

6.2.4, §5:

> For such an object that does not have a variable length array type, its lifetime extends
>   from entry into the block with which it is associated until execution of that block ends in
>   anyway.(Entering an enclosed block or calling a function suspends, but does not end,
>   execution of the current block.) If the block is entered recursively,anew instance of the
>   object is created each time. The initial value of the object is indeterminate. If an
>   initialization is specified for the object, it is performed each time the declaration is
>   reached in the execution of the block; otherwise, the value becomes indeterminate each
>   time the declaration is reached.

6.7.8, §10:

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly,its value is indeterminate. If an object that has static storage duration is not initialized explicitly, then:
>
> > — if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
> >
> > — if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive orunsigned) zero;
> >
> > — if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules;
> >
> > — if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules.

3.17.2, §1:

indeterminate value: either an unspecified value or a trap representation

3.17.3, §1:

unspecified value: valid value of the relevant type where this International Standard imposes no requirements on which value is chosen in any instance. NOTE An unspecified value cannot be a trap representation.

Comment: "(some garbage value" ... or trap representation or anything ... ")"

Comment: @pmg,what's `trap representation `?

Comment: "undefined value" should be "indeterminate value" to use the wording of the C99 standard. A trap representation is a bit pattern in memory that causes undefined behavior if you access it with an l-value of type other than `char`.

Comment: @cpuer: a `trap representation` is an arrangement of bits that does not represent a valid value. Most current computers use all bit representations for different and valid values, especially in integer types, but the language does not mandate that. **A trap representation is not a garbage value.**

Answer (score 7):

`automatic` (local) variables are not guaranteed to be zero, can contain garbage.

`global` variables and `static` variables are guaranteed to be zero.

Answer (score 5):

Variables declared (as `int`)at **file scope** are initialized to 0.

Example

```
int i;
int main()
{
   int x;
   printf("%d",i); // prints 0
   printf("%d",x); // prints some unspecified value
}
```

> Is it guranteed that un-initialized variable will have 0 value in c at all?

Nopes! That doesn't hold for variables declared at function scope.

Comment: The `printf("%d",x);` statement can also make your *NUM LOCK* light blink (especially if your architecture allows for trap representations in `int`s)

Comment: @pmg : Yes! After all the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Slightly wrong. You could *declare* `int x;` at file scope, and still have a definition `int x=1;` somewhere else. :)

Comment: I was convinced that this is how C works, but experienced something differnt. In a small program, __x was zero__. Since x was zero in consequent executions, I don't think it was zero by chance. Could it be that newer compilers result in a different behavior?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how the variable is allocated. Statically allocated variables are initialized to zero, whereas variables allocated on the stack or with `malloc()` are not.