# Global PyObject* variable in C-Python extension

Tags: python, c

In a C extension to my Python program, I am trying to improve performance by setting two of the inputs to the main C function (which is called millions of times) as global variables, as they don't change often, so that I don't have to keep supplying them from Python using a lambda wrapper to the C function (which wastes a nontrivial amount of time). My code looks like this. First I declare the global variables at the top of the file:

```
unsigned char* splitArray;
PyObject* wordCmp;
```

Then the Python API function to set them:

```
static PyObject* py_set_globals(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    free(wordCmp);
    free(splitArray);

    char* splitChars;
    PyObject* wordC;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "sO", &splitChars, &wordC))
        return NULL;

    wordCmp = (PyObject*)malloc(sizeof(PyObject));
    memcpy(wordCmp, wordC, sizeof(PyObject));
    splitArray = splitchars_to_mapping(splitChars);

    return Py_BuildValue("");
}
```

In this case, splitArray is assigned to a 128-character array which is malloc'ed in the function splitchars_to_mapping, and wordCmp is a Python function object that is passed to C. Anyway, as far as I can tell, the char* splitArray works fine as a global variable, but when I later try to call wordCmp using PyEval_CallObject, Python/C crashes. So I have two questions:

1. Why doesn't C crash immediately when I try to free the uninitialized pointers wordCmp and splitArray at the beginning of the function?
2. Why am I unable to call wordCmp later when I have properly stored it on the heap and saved a reference to it as a global?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As to the first question, why it doesn't crash when free'ing uninitialized global variables, that's because global (and static) variables are initialized to `zero` when the program is loaded ([guaranteed by the standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6212973/1157444)) and when you call `free()` with `NULL` (or zero) it does nothing.

From man [free(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/free):

> free(ptr) has already been called before, undefined behavior occurs. 
>   **If ptr is NULL, no operation is performed.**

**Edit**:
Your second question is related to fact that you're trying to copy a `PyObject` and you shouldn't do that, as the `PyObject` structure could contain pointers and you can't do *deep* copying because you don't have access to that structure, you should however increment the reference count and keep the reference around for later use, note that when you use `O` the reference count is *not* incremented, from the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/arg.html):

> O (object) [PyObject *]
>       Store a Python object (without any conversion) in a C object pointer. The C program thus receives the actual object that was
>   passed. **The object’s reference count is not increased.**

So you should increment the reference yourself, see this [example](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html#calling-python-functions-from-c)

```
static PyObject *my_callback = NULL;

static PyObject* my_set_callback(PyObject *dummy, PyObject *args)
{
    PyObject *result = NULL;    
    if (PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O:set_callback", &my_callback)) {
        if (!PyCallable_Check(my_callback)) {
            PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "parameter must be callable");
            return NULL;
        }
        Py_XINCREF(my_callback); /* Add a reference to new callback */           
        Py_INCREF(Py_None);      /* Boilerplate to return "None" */
        result = Py_None;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Okay, thanks for that. So my declarations are equivalent to "unsigned char* splitArray = NULL; PyObject* wordCmp = NULL;"?

Comment: @dpitch40 yes it's guaranteed by the standard, see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6212973/1157444