# No display of array

Tags: c, arrays

The following is my implementation of the SPOJ problem: http://www.spoj.com/problems/FCTRL2/

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--)
    {
        int carry=0,k,i,j,num,arr[1000]={1};
        scanf("%d",&num);
        for(i=1;i<=num;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<=k;j++)
            {
                arr[j]=arr[j]*i+carry;
                carry=arr[j]/10;
                arr[j]=arr[j]%10;
            }
            while(carry)
            {
                k++;
                arr[k]=carry%10;
                carry/=10;
            }
        }
        for(i=k;i>=0;i--)//doubt
        {
            printf("%d",arr[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I guess there is a mistake in displaying array in reverse direction, but when I change the condition i.e for(i=0;i<=k;i++) it prints the array.
Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: `j<=k` : `k` isn't initialized.

Comment: And where do you initialize `k`? Since you never do that, its value will be *indeterminate* and using it will lead to *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int carry=0,k,i,j,num,arr[1000]={1};

for(j=0;j<=k;j++)
```

`k` is not initialized here, and will have an indeterminate value.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6212973/5708620

> External and static variables are initialized to zero by default, this
>   is guaranteed. Automatic and register variables that do not have en
>   explicit initializer will have an indeterminate value (either an
>   unspecified value or a trap representation).

Answer (score 0):

Yes ,,It depends upon the compiler and OS version.Generally i am guessing in your case it might has been assigned with garbage value.