# Learning C: if and functions not executing in loop

Tags: c

I have started relearning C (self study), and ran into a problem with an if statement not always executing inside of a loop.  What's odd is that on it's own, the function executes correctly, but unless I add a printf() statement referencing the variable in the loop then it won't attempt to test the if statement.

Specifically, the line `printf("%d ", aCounter);` in the while loop in the main(void) function is what's required for it to attempt test the if statement.  I had a similar problem using a for loop (as you can see it's commented out).  I am confused as to why it doesn't test the if statement without the printf() mentioned.  And yet it does successfully find: 1, 6, 24, 28, and 496 with the printf() statement.  It only finds "1" without it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int isPerfect(unsigned int n);

int main(void) {
    /* for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
        if (isPerfect(i) == 1) {
            printf("%d is perfect\n", i);
        }
    }
    */
   int aCounter = 0;
   while (aCounter < 1000) {
        aCounter++;
        if (isPerfect(aCounter) == 1 ) {
            printf("%d is perfect\n", aCounter);
            for (int aTemp = 1; aTemp < aCounter; aTemp++) {
                if (aCounter % aTemp ==0) {
                    printf("%d is a factor of %d\n", aTemp, aCounter);
                }
            }
        }
        printf("%d ", aCounter);
        //aCounter++;
   }
   
   int a = 6;
   if (isPerfect(a) == 1 ) {
       printf("%d is perfect\n", a);
   }

    printf("%d is perfect: %d\n", 6, isPerfect(6));
    printf("%d is NOT perfect: %d\n", 8, isPerfect(8));
    printf("%d is perfect: %d\n", 6, isPerfect(6));

}

int isPerfect(unsigned int n) {
    int aNumber;
    for (int i =1; i <= n; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            aNumber += i;
            if (aNumber == n)
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `aNumber` is uninitialized in the `isPerfect` function.  This is undefined behavior because using the `+=` operator requires that this variable has a deterministic initial value.

Comment: In other words, do `int aNumber = 0;`

Comment: The posted code does not cleanly compile!.   When compiling, always enable the warnings (the posted code outputs a lot of warnings).  For `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=-gnu11`  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure about the expected output of your program, but I can see that inside the `isPerfect(unsigned int n)` function, we have a statement `aNumber += i;` which basically does is `aNumber = aNumber + 1;`, i.e, update the value of `aNumber` by 1. But as we can see, in the very first statement inside this function where `aNumber` is defined, it isn't initialized, so updating its value to 1 seems pointless as it's previous value is unknown. Initializing its value , let's say `int aNumber = 0;`
will do the job.

**But uninitialized variable in C need not always contain a garbage value.**

> automatic (local) variables are not guaranteed to be zero, can contain
> garbage but global variables and static variables are guaranteed to be
> zero

please refer to this post [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6212921/is-un-initialized-integer-always-default-to-0-in-c) for more details.

.